# Could not set property QwizardPage register field method warning

Tags: c++, qt

I Have a Wizard page class and the ui is designed in designer and ui has a label and list widget (ObjectName :listwidget).Now i register the label in constructor of the class and in the signal on_listwidget_itemselectionChanged() i set the label text with the number of selection and also use setfield to change the value. Now i access using field in my another page. I get the value but get an warning saying could not write the property. how can i solve it. Below is the code sample:

```
#include "ui.h"
class Page1
{
Page1()
{
registerfield("name", Label);
}

on_listWidget_itemSelectionChanged()
{
value = listwidget->selectedItems().size();
label->setText(QString::number(value));
setField("name", QString::number(value)); // With out setting i am not able to get the value/string
}
}; 

#include "ui2.h"
class Page2
{
Page2(){};
initializePage()
{
QString tmp = field("name").toString();

// Here i get the value only when i use setfield or else i get 0.
// Additionally in both case i get the warning "Could not set the property"
}
};
```

Comment: What is `Label` in `registerfield("name", Label);`? Please read again what docs say about `QWizardPage::registerField()` function.

Comment: @vahancho: Label is a pointer to my QLabel widget.

Comment: Well, but `QLabel` isn't listed among widgets you don't need to specify the property for. You could try to register it in the following way: `registerfield("name", Label, "text");` instead. It's still bad idea to use a label for field, as user cannot edit QLabel text anyway. Try to use QLineEdit instead.

Comment: @vahancho: I need qlabel just to show how many items were selected by the user. I tried the syntax as u mentioned but did not work :(